# How to solve for the matrix $X$ if given the equation $X^2+AX=B$ where $A$ and $B$ are known matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

We want to solve $X^2+AX=B$ or $X^2+AX-B=0$ where $X$ is the unknown. In order to simplify the analysis, I tried to look at only $2\times 2$ matrices but that yields a horrendous system of equations. Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: do you really know the values of $A,B$? or you want to solve for every $A,B$ separately?

Comment: If $A,B$ are diagonal there may be more than $2^n$ solutions.

Comment: @yanko I know the values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Then I believe you can try to treat those matrices as numbers, you know the general solution for numbers it is $$\frac{-A\pm \sqrt{A^2+4B}}{2A}$$ So you will have to find a square matrix (i.e a matrix $C$ such that $C^2=A^2+4B$) and the inverse of $A$.

Comment: Aahh can you really do that?

Comment: This needs to suppose $AX=XA$, as explained in my answer below so this gives only solutions that are commuting with $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix equation $X^2+AX=B$ is a special case of the algebraic Riccati equation
$$
XBX + XA − DX − C = 0,
$$
which can be solved using Jordan chains. For references see [this article](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_20_matrix_equ.pdf), in particular the reference $[4]$, the book by Lancaster and Rodman.
Note that such quadratic matrix equations need not have a solution: consider the matrix equation
$$
X^2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea if you want to first try to find solutions $X$ such that $XA=AX$ :

If $$X^2+AX-B=0\;\text{ and}\;AX=XA$$ then  : $$(2X+A)^2=4B+A^2$$
This leads us to solve an equation of form:$$Y^2=M$$where $Y$ is the unknown and $M$ is given.